# Can anyone provide an example of a dynamodb document client upsert?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm looking for a non trivial upsert example in node for [AWS dynamodb's DocumentClient](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#update-property). Can someone share a sample that has worked for them?

I would like to see an example that sets a created_at, updated_at and a id field on creating the record but only sets the updated_at when the record is found and updated.

Answer (score 7):

This should achieve your goal.  My apologies, as I missed your criteria in my original posting.  I am assuming `id` is the key in your table.

```
'use strict';

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var ec2 = new AWS.EC2({ apiVersion: '2016-09-15' });
var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';

var ret = {};
const ddbTbl = 'table_name';

var date = new Date();
var dateAsIso = date.toISOString();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var key = 'bar';
    var params = {
        TableName: ddbTbl,
        Key: {
            "id": key
        },
        UpdateExpression: "set #u = :t, #c = if_not_exists(#c, :t)",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            "#u": "updated_at",
            "#c": "created_at"
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":t": dateAsIso
        },
        ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"
    };
    ddb.update(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
            ret.ddbUpdate = err;
            callback(null, {success: false, message: ["ddb upsert failed"], payload: ret});
            // or use the regular callback for failures if you don't want to do your own envelope response
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            ret.ddbUpdate = data;
            callback(null, {success: true, message: ["ddb upsert succeeded"], payload: ret});
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: How do you set a created_at field on creating a record and only an updated_at field when the record already exists?

Comment: The doc is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET.PreventingAttributeOverwrites) if anyone wants it.

Comment: @DuocTran that's the doc for using the CLI - not the SDK as the OP is...